# FutureBuilder body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my error code:

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
> Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.dart(body_might_complete_normally)"

And here is the relevant code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: firebase,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError){
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Error"),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text("${snapshot.error}"),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please copy paste the actual code rather than linking to a picture.

Comment: It looks like your code inly returns something if there is an error. Is that the intention?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ]'s and see the [tour]. The point of Stackoverflow is to be a reusable resource, given your question title this isn't going to help anyone else out. And the code is a picture so you can't search on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any **Builder** in Flutter requires a **Widget** to be returned.
If you want the function to end without displaying anything - then **return a SizedBox**.

```dart
if( snapshot.hasError ) {
    ...
}
return const SizedBox();
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is the builder arguments is of return type Widget(non-nullable) And in the code that is above, you are returning a Scaffold within a if statement, which means the function won't return anything in the else case.

To resolve the issue, you might have to make sure that your code returns a widget in all possible flows of execution.

you can add this else part to resolve

```
    else {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar('NO ERROR'),
        body: Center(child: Text('Loaded Succesfully'),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think better use like this in body.

```
body:Center(
child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
)
```